# How to Know When a Google Cloud Run Instance Stops Serving Traffic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm aware that Google Cloud Run will send SIGTERM when it's actually shutting an instance down, but what I need is to identify when an instance of a container is no longer serving traffic, since they can continue to run for 15 minutes to an hour after that.

Is that possible?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You do not pay for idle instances.

Comment: As long as your instance is living, your instance is ready to serve traffic (in the load balancer registry). Why do you want to know that?

Comment: @JohnHanley Because I have running processes on there that I don't want running in duplicate (connecting to a WebSocket server and sending out notifications). I guess I shouldn't be running this on Cloud Run.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks. See my answer to John. Because I have a process running on there that I don't want running in duplicate.

Comment: Set a max instance to 1. You will have only 1 active instance (but in rare transient cases, you could have 2)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks. That doesn't help and already done along with always allocating the CPU. Any time a build is done the previous instance keeps running for some time. I also find two instances being started up sometimes after a new build which is weird although one always gets shut down quickly when that happens.

Comment: You might do something wrong with your design. Why only 1 instance must run at the same time? It's not a serverless horizontally scalable app.

Comment: Agreed, Cloud Run is not really the right place for it, it's an experimentation and research and learning project.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, using Cloud Logging or Cloud Monitoring API could allow to get this information, for example in cloud logging getting the last requests using the request below:

```html
resource.type = "cloud_run_revision"
resource.labels.service_name = "backend"
resource.labels.location = "europe-west3"
httpRequest:*
```

You can use the gcloud cli(gcloud logging read) or the console