# Is there any logs for cloud run container from idle to shutting/stopped?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-cloud-run

As official GCP blog picture below

I want to know if any of my CloudRun load balance containers

From idle to shutting/stopped because there are no api requests

Is there any record on GCP?

[image: Lifecycle of a container on Cloud Run]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#instance-shutdown), you can build your application to handle a SIGTERM signal.

> Before shutting down an instance, Cloud Run sends a SIGTERM signal to all the containers in an instance, indicating the start of a 10 second period before the actual shutdown occurs, at which point Cloud Run sends a SIGKILL signal.

Check with this documentation on [`how to handle SIGTERMs on Cloud Run`](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/graceful-shutdowns-cloud-run-deep-dive) so that your shutdowns will be graceful rather than abrupt.

To check the logs, see this section in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/graceful-shutdowns-cloud-run-deep-dive),

> The scale-to-zero will trigger a SIGTERM signal to be sent to your container before it is shut down, and you can see the graceful shutdown routine executed in the Logs tab

Also have a look at this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging) and [SF link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73735370/18265702).